# Combination problem involving multiple conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From a group of 12 students, 8 are to be chosen for an excursion. There are 3 students who decide that either of them will join or none of them will join. In how many ways can the 8 be chosen?
Here two conditions such as 'either' and 'none' are used. I find it difficult to analyse the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have two cases:  if they all come, you need to select $5$ from the remaining $9$, otherwise you need to select $8$ from the remaining $9$.  These are disjoint, so you can add them.